# how I can git merge automatic

Tags: git

When I run `git pull origin feature/siteRedesizhn` I am getting a list of 41 file with errors

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): .default/style.css deleted in d1c66866cb543b104368e4eff9d980424460bcf4 and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of .default/style.css left in tree.
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in slider_main_custom/template.php
```

How can I get git merge all mutations both in the thread `feature/siteRedesizhn` in my local repository, without looking and without altering the files manually?
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Human judgement is necessary for resolving a merge conflict in git. There isnt a way to do it automatically, you have to decide what stays and what gets deleted in a conflicting file.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, conflicts should be a stop-signs to the automation process, so a human will need to decide how to solve it.
Still, you can decide to force an --ours or --theirs strategy so the merge will take on of the parents files as is without raising a conflict.
This should be used with much care and better not used at all.

For detailed merge strategy and much more, refer to: https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging